# JQM A / B / C graded device support matrix effects

Tags: css, ajax, jquery-mobile

I've read the jqm browser support matrix, but couldn't figure out, how the different grades are affecting my site on older / B-grade browsers.

#### A-grade – Full enhanced experience with Ajax-based animated page transitions

this is trivial, full support.

#### B-grade – Enhanced experience except without Ajax navigation features

What does that mean? JQM enhances my page, but doesn't supports transitions/.changepage() / etc? What functionality do I really lose on this grade?

#### C-grade – Basic, non-enhanced HTML experience that is still functional

Does that mean, that my site is not supported on these devices and I have to build a complete new page that only runs on plain html / simple css?

Comment: You may need to create a simple site for such devices. On load, check the value of `$.support.ajax`, if it false, then redirect user to a simple site.

Comment: hm, maybe my question is not the best one. If my browser would be classified as B-grade, what would my page look like on it and what features do I loose, if "ajax navigation features" are not availible? The documentiation says nothing about that, only that features are missing but nothing about what exactly in detail.